# "Cannot find module" error on Heroku when deploying

Tags: javascript, heroku, webpack

So, I am making an app with React, and I am deploying it to Heroku afterwards. Everything works great in localhost and without any errors, and webpack also compiles with no errors. I have set env variales on Heroku as well.

However, when I deploy it to Heroku I get a blank screen and this error in console(I am requiring TodoApi properly and have tried various ways - import etc., it works in localhost with no issues):

I am trying to figure out it for days, so any help is much appreciated.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "TodoApi"
    at bundle.js:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:20)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:20)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:3)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
```

Here are my webpack and package.json files:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var envFile = require('node-env-file');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

try {
    envFile(path.join(__dirname, 'config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.env'));
} catch(e) {

}

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx'
  ],
  externals: {
      jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          '$': 'jquery',
          'jQuery': 'jquery'
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compressor: {
              warnings: false
          }
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
          API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY),
          AUTH_DOMAIN: JSON.stringify(process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN),
          DATABASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.DATABASE_URL),
          STORAGE_BUCKET: JSON.stringify(process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET),
          MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID)
        }
      })
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    modulesDirectories: [
        'node_modules',
        './app/components',
        './app/api'
    ],
    alias: {
        app: 'app',
        applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss',
        actions: 'app/actions/actions.jsx',
        reducers: 'app/reducers/reducers.jsx',
        configureStore: 'app/store/configureStore.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? undefined : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};


{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ReactApp",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test karma start",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "npm run build && node server.js"
  },
  "author": "John Smith",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "deep-freeze-strict": "^1.1.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.3.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "node-env-file": "^0.1.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-loader": "^0.6.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.1",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3"
  }
}

var React = require('react');
var { connect } = require('react-redux');
import Todo from 'Todo';
var TodoApi = require('TodoApi');

export var TodoList = React.createClass ({
    render: function() {
        var { todos, showCompleted, searchText } = this.props;
        var renderTodos = () => {
            var filteredTodos = TodoApi.filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchText);

            if(filteredTodos.length === 0) {
                return (
                    <p className="container__message">No tasks</p>
                );
            }
            return filteredTodos.map((todo) => {
                return (
                    //add unique key prop to keep track of individual components
                    <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />
                );
            });
        };
        return (
            <div>
                {renderTodos()}
            </div>
        );  
    }
});

export default connect(
    (state) => {
        return state;
    }
)(TodoList);
```

Comment: is TodoApi an external package?

Comment: I had this issue years ago trying to use Node.js's MongoDB driver on Heroku so it's not a module-specific issue. Never found an answer and I ended up having to use Digitalocean instead.

Comment: Which O.S. is your localhost based?

Comment: Looks like you dont have the TodoApi in your package.json. Try adding it to your package.json. And use npm i --save packagename

Comment: Did you try to remove your local node modules and reinstall them? You might be able to replicate locally at that point.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I am working on Win 7 Pro 64bit. @Peter G thanks for the info

Comment: A possible hint. Windows is case insensitive while Heroku is case sensitive. Be careful if you are trying to require the TodoApi package with uppercase. I am unaware if there is any npm package name with uppercases. I don't think so because in later versions you are forced to lowercase the package name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly what it says. The TodoApi.

Locally it will work because the TodoApi is probably in your "node_modules" directory. (You didn't include it locally in your index.html did you?) The problem is that it is not packed into the deployment package. That's why it doesn't work.

First, don't know if you noticed but you (wan't to) include *node_modules* under *modulesDirectories* and later under *module.loaders* you exclude it again. Luckily for you it didn't include, otherwise you would still be building, lol. Besides that you can just **delete** the *modulesDirectories* passage. And don't ever think it's a good idea to include *node_modules* as a directory into anything. ;)

I would do the following to bring some structure, so you can clearly see what is included and what not. At the top of you webpack define some absolute directories:

```
// Absolute directories
const root    = (...dir) => path.resolve(__dirname, ...dir);
const lib     = root('lib'),
      src     = root('src'), // or 'app'
      project = root('.');
```

This you know for sure what directory is assigned and it reads easier.
Then set your entry-file.

```
const entry   = root('app/app.jsx');
```

And change it under module exports:

```
root: src,
context: src,
entry: entry,
...
```

I always set the context to my src directory, that means that so far webpack is concerned src is the top directory. Remove the other stuff under entry.

I would also comment out the Uglify plugin while you don't have the build working yet, just to exclude stuff that can create error's of their own.

Install the *webpack-bundle-analyzer*.

```
npm i --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer
```

And add it to your webpack plugins like this:

```
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        analyzerMode: 'server',
        analyzerHost: 'localhost',
        analyzerPort: 9002,
        reportFilename: 'report.html',
        openAnalyzer: true,
        // Log level. Can be 'info', 'warn', 'error' or 'silent'.
        logLevel: 'info'
      })
```

This will open a nice graphical view of your package after the build. One of the blocks needs to mention "TodoApi" and then you're good. If you first add the BundleAnalyzerPlugin without changing your code, then you can see that the TodoApi probably isn't in there.

Comment: p.s. A lot of modules that are used to develop are in your dependencies and should be in your devDependencies. (e.a. *-loader, test, sass, etc.). You really should clean-up and check what you are working with. A good clean structure and code-style to start with will save you a tof time fixing stuff...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in `resolve` part of your webpack configuration file. It seems `resolve.modulesDirectories` doesn't do it job correctly when you deploy to Heroku. I feel it make more sense to configure resolving your './app/components' and './app/api' with `resolve.root` instead of `resolve.modulesDirectories`. So try out following `resolve` configuration and probably it will work with Heroku.

```
resolve: {
    root: [
        __dirname,
        path.resolve(__dirname, "app/components"),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "app/api")
    ],
    modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules' ],
    alias: {
        app: 'app',
        applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss',
        actions: 'app/actions/actions.jsx',
        reducers: 'app/reducers/reducers.jsx',
        configureStore: 'app/store/configureStore.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are requiring `TodoApi` but this package doesn't exist in your `package.json`

In your `TodoList.jsx` Component

`var TodoApi = require("TodoApi");`

A quick look through the repo shows that the package doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: I have included it later but the issue remains, so the app works in localhost, this only happens when I deploy it to Heroku.. I have edited post and included my current TodoList component. So, TodoApi is just a jsx file in the api folder

Comment: Okay, then the issue is that you need to specify the path to the `TodoApi`. `var TodoApi = require('../api/TodoApi')`

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried that and all variations, with imports and from various paths, it seems that this is not an issue. In case of a bad path I suppose that app would break right away on localhost.... I also thought that I should maybe try stage-1 and latest babel preset, but I always get the same error. My best guess that it has something to do with Heroku or how it reads the paths, maybe it treats the npm modules differently than on local machine...?